# wordpress get_the_terms hierarchical (parents -> childs)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to list all custom terms of post, but I don't have idea how to create a hierarchical list.

I have custom taxonomy like

```
- Tax1
 - subtax1.1
 - subtax1.2
 - subtax1.3
- Tax2
 - subtax2.1
 - subtax2.2
 - subtax2.3
```

And for example my custom post is in `subtax1.1`, `subtax1.2` and `subtax2.2`

**So I want to achieve list like this:**

```
- Tax1
 - subtax1.1
 - subtax1.2
- Tax2
 - subtax2.2
```

How I can do that? `get_the_terms()` function doesn't apply parent argument.
Outside the post I have hierchical list made of `get_terms()` function, but there is parent argument.

Comment: Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/, with style=list this can generate a nested UL/LI construct for your. (Careful, it does not put `<ul></ul>` around the result on the outermost level, so you will have to add that yourself.)

Comment: are you sure wp_list_categories works on current post? I don't want to list out all my taxonomies, just the taxonomies of current post

Comment: Check the description of the arguments, it says you can pass in additional parameters as described elsewhere. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/ describes the `object_ids` parameter: _“Results will be limited to terms associated with these objects.”_